# What is the distribution of an arrival time in a Poisson processes conditioned on the value of another arrival time?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

**The problem**: Customer arrival times are modeled by a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 10$. $X(t)$ refers to the number of customers who have arrived by time $t$, where $0 < t \le 1$. Assume that $\{S_i : i = 1,...,n\}$ represents the arrival times, so customer $i$ arrives at time $S_i$.

> Determine the distribution of $S_1$ given that the fifth customer arrived exactly one hour after the bank was open.

**My attempt**: I'm not really sure how to solve this because I only know how arrival times are distributed when conditioned on $N(t) = n$. I know that $S_5 = 1$ implies that $X(1) = 5$. I first tried doing:

$$Pr(S_1 = s | S_5 = 1) = \frac{Pr(S_1 = s \bigcap S_5 = 1)}{Pr(S_5 = 5)}$$

Then:

$$\frac{Pr(S_1 = s \bigcap S_5 = 1)}{Pr(S_5 = 5)} = \frac{Pr(S_1 = s \bigcap X(1) = 5)}{Pr(S_5 = 1)}$$

I know that the lower probability has a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha = 5$ and $\beta = 10$. But I'm not sure what to do with the top one or whether this is even the correct approach at all.

**The key problem I have is**: how can I solve for $Pr(S_1 = s \bigcap S_5 = 1)$? I know that if they were interarrival times, I could use the product since they're independent variables. But $S_1$ and $S_5$ are dependent variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with probability denisities rather than mass, otherwise okay.

Note that (in a Poisson Process) the wait time (inter-arival time) before the arrival of the first customer will be independent of the *subseqent* wait time until the arrival of the fifth customer.   Further, the later has identical distribution as the wait time before the fourth arrival.

That is, $S_1, S_5-S_1$ are independent, and $S_5-S_1$ and $S_4$ have identical distributions, so:

$$\begin{align}f(S_1=t\mid S_5=1) &= \dfrac{f(S_1=t)~f(S_5-S_1=1-t)}{f(S_5=1)} \\[1ex] &= \dfrac{f(S_1=t)~f(S_4=1-t)}{f(S_5=1)}\end{align}$$

---

Now, $f(S_k=\tau) = \dfrac{\lambda^k \tau^{k-1} e^{-\lambda \tau}}{(k-1)!}\mathbf 1_{\tau\in[0;\infty), k\in[1;\infty){\cap}\Bbb N}$, which is the *probability density function* for an Erlang distribution, as you noted.   So you will obtain a rather neat result.   Do you recognise what it is?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you clarify, though, on what you mean by "dealing with probability densities rather than mass"? Also, why is $Pr(S_1 = t \bigcap S_5 = 1) = Pr(S_1 = t) Pr(S_5 - S_1 = 1 - t)$? I can tell that the interval of time between $S_1$ and $S_5$ is of length 1 - t, but I don't understand how that works in terms of probability concepts.

Comment: The *inter-arrival times* are **continuous** random variables, so they have no probability *mass* at any discrete point (in time).  Please avoid dividing by zero. $$\Pr(S_n=t)=0$$ **Poisson processes** are *memoryless* so the interarrival time until *future* arrivals does not depend on the time of any *past* arrivals.  $$f(S_5-S_1=1-t\mid S_1=t)=f(S_5-S_1=1-t)$$

Comment: Oh, I see. I knew that a Poisson process had independent increments, but until now I hadn't been able to grasp the meaning mathematically. As for what the result is, I only got $\frac{(1-s)^3}{4}$, which I don't immediately recognize. Does it have significance?

Comment: That should be $4(1-s)^3~\mathbf 1_{0\lt t\lt 1}$ , the distribution of the *first (or least) order statistic* for a set of *four* independent samples from a *uniform distribution* over $(0;1)$.  It is the probability that one from the four samples occurs at time $t$ and the other three occur between $t$ and $1$.

Comment: Woops, it looks like you're right--I made a tiny arithmetic error in the cancellation of the factorials. Hm, that's interesting. I haven't worked enough with order statistics to recognize the formula, but that will all change this spring break. All I currently know by heart are the formulas $S_{X_{(1)}} (x) = [S_X (x)]^n$ and $F_{X_{(n)}} (x) = [F_X (x)]^n$.

Comment: Indeed, and $f_{X_{(1)}}(x) = \dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d ~x} S_{X_{(1)}}(x) = n f_X(x) [S_X(x)]^{n-1}$